# PHP Unable to load some 32-bit dynamic libraries on a 64-bit machine

Tags: linux, php, php5

I am being hit by following error when I try to run installation of a bugtracker named 'The Bug Genie'. I have opensuse 11.3 64bit on my system and so I found these missing .so files in /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/. How can I install 32-bit versions of these libraries or anyother idea to make it work?

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/gd.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/extensions/gd.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mbstring.so'
>   - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mbstring.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysql.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysqli.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/extensions/mysqli.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on
>   line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo_mysql.so'
>   - /usr/lib/php5/extensions/pdo_mysql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on
>   line 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a 64-bit version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks. I checked again and found that I had php-i586 installed. Don't know  how i missed this.